# Oracle - part of db replication - good practices

Tags: oracle, replication

question is about good practices, does it got any sense ...
The scenario:

We need to share an application to the outside world. Application uses part of the views from main production db:

a) Production db - ORACLE, used in internal network
b) We need share some views - data from db in point A (prod)

Now, someone, due to security matters, come up with the idea that the db that will be used by application, needs to be sepaparate and data should be replicated, copied from main database every n minutes to be up to date ...

My questions:

a) is it a good practice ?
b) does it have any sense ? Is it common to use this scenario ?
c) Any advice ?

Much appreciated any help.

Kindest regards

Comment: Final architecture could depend on a lot of things, but if there's no way to allow indirect network connections (like through an intermediate application server) by the application to your internal network, then replication is absolutely an option. The method of replication will depend on how much data is involved and how close to real-time that data needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately (to cloning the database), you can create another user within the same database and `GRANT` them only the `SELECT` privilege on the limited number of views (owned by your primary users) that you want them to access and then have the external application connect to the database via that lower-privileged user. That way they can only see those views (and not all the tables) and only have read access (not read-write access) and you do not have to maintain two databases or push updates around your network.